# How to remove the search fields in Twentytwelve

Tags: customization

Just wanting to ask the forum here, on how would i remove the search field in the Wordpress theme twentytwelve.

I did find a similar topic here and tried to follow through with the suggested code instructions but unfortunately i wasn't so successful.

I also posted this question in another thread but this has since been removed.
I gather since this wasn't my own topic.
Being new here and this is my very first thread the moderator should have at least warned me before deleting my question and i would have been more happy to remove the question i wrote.

So here i go i will ask again and post this here in my very own thread.
Hopefully i wont be removed this time and that i have asked this in the correct discussion forum.

I would appreciate what ever help you could give to me.

I have the code below

Thanks in advance.

index.php

```
<?php if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) :
        // Show a different message to a logged-in user who can add posts.
    ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'No posts to display', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php printf( __( 'Ready to publish your first post? <a href="%s">Get started here</a>.', 'twentytwelve' ), admin_url( 'post-new.php' ) ); ?></p>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <?php else :
        // Show the default message to everyone else.
    ?>
        <header class="entry-header">
            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php _e( 'Nothing Found', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></h1>
        </header>

        <div class="entry-content">
            <p><?php _e( 'Apologies, but no results were found. Perhaps searching will help find a related post.', 'twentytwelve' ); ?></p>
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; // end current_user_can() check ?>

    </article><!-- #post-0 -->

<?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**get_search_form()**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) displays the search form. So you can either remove it or comment it out.

My advice would be to create a child theme, copy the necessary template files you would need working on and edit them so your customization's don't get overwritten on theme update.

Comment: Thank you Mr Tunja

That worked great.

I just commented out this line below as you suggested.

I also made a back of the file should i need it later rather than a child theme as it was quicker and easier.

Regards
Tony

    <?php /* else :
    // Show the default message to everyone else.
   */ ?>